# Let $f$ be measurable then prove a certain set is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Question: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable.  Prove $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:f(x)\geq f(y)\}$ is measurable.

My thoughts: I was hoping that there would be a way to "pull back" into an open set, since open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable.  I was trying to just use the definition of a measurable function, but I am just getting thrown off by the $f(x)\geq f(y)$ bit, and how that affects everything.  Also, I was wondering if you could provide any insight as to dealing with problems like this.  In particular, if given a measurable function $f$, what is a good way of going about dealing with questions regarding a set with elements depending on $f$...

Any thoughts, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we have that the function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, where $\phi(x,y)=x-y$ is measurable since it is continuous. So is the function $F(x,y)=(f(x),f(y))$ (from $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$), since $f$ is measurable. Then $\phi\circ F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Now, \begin{align}
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:f(x)\geq f(y)\} 
&= 
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:f(x)-f(y)\geq 0\}
\\&= 
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: \ \phi(f(x),f(y))\geq 0 \}
\\&=
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:\ \phi\circ F(x,y)\geq0\}
\\&=
(\phi\circ F)^{-1}\big([0,+\infty)\big)
\end{align}
and thus it is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: A measurable function of a measurable function need not be measurable. But a continuous  function of a measurable function is measurable, and you have that.

Comment: In that particular case I believe that continuity is not necessary. It would matter if we considered different $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @zhw. in general of course you are right. thanks